# Motion near the local maximum of potential energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy

Particle is moving along the $x$ axis in the field with potential energy $U(x)$. $U(x) $has local maximum at $x=0$, and the total energy of particle is equal to $E=U(0)$.

I'm supposed to find how the particle is moving near the point $x=0$, when it is approaching this point:

a) using Lagrangian

b) using Newton equations

All I came up is that from the equation $F=-\frac{dU}{dx}$ we have that $F(0)=0$ (because U has maximum at 0). I was thinking about using now the Newton equation $F=ma$, so that $ma=0 \to $ x(t) is linear near 0, but I don't think it is correct.

As to (a), I think that lagrangian will be as usual: $L= \frac{mv^{2}}{2}-U$, where $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$. I can calculate then that $\frac{dL}{dx}(0)=0$, but I don't know if it is useful at all.

Any help will be appreciate :)

Comment: Be careful with where you are calculating your functions in your equations. The equation $ma = 0$ is true only at $x=0$. If you want to find out how $F$ and $a$ behave around $x=0$, you need to calculate $dU/dx$ not only at that point, but around it too. My suggestion is to approximate U(x) as a parabola around that point with unknown coefficients, and then calculate the derivative of that expression.Using that in $F=ma$ will give a linear ODE for x(t), which you should be able to solve.

Comment: As for the Lagrangian method, I think you should use Euler-Lagrange's equation to obtain the equations of motion. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: @LucasBaldo Thanks a lot for your comments! By approximating U(x) by $bx^2+cx+d$ (b<0), I get from $U'(0)=0$ that $U(x)=bx^2+d$. Then I get the linear ODE $ma=2bx$, which gave me result $x(t)=C_1e^{\sqrt{\frac{2b}{m}}t}+C_2e^{-\sqrt{\frac{2b}{m}}t}$. Is that a correct way?

Comment: @LucasBaldo As for the Lagrangian method: I get the result $F=-\frac{dU}{dx}$ from Euler-Lagrange's equations: for $L=\frac{mv^2}{2}-U(x)$ we get $\frac{d}{dt}(mv)=\frac{d(-U(x))}{dx}$, which is just $ma=-\frac{dU}{dx}$. Now I can do it of course the same way as before, but I'm not sure if that is what you were thinking of?

Comment: my pleasure. I didn't do all the calculations myself, but I believe you must also be careful about the sign of the term inside the $ln$, so that function is well defined, when you integrate the ODE. There might be a need to split the solution into a $t>0$ and a $t<0$ part. I'm not 100% sure, but you should check it out

Comment: As for the Lagrangian method. It seems about right too, you just reach the same conclusion through a more general way. The only thing I would be careful about is that the usual notation in this method is to use $\dot{x}$ for velocity instead of $v$, but I guess that's just convention.